# Android: project set up for unit and functional tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

I'm trying to incorporate more unit tests, specifically Robolectric test into my project. Right now I already have some functional test that are in my `androidTest` package. The problem is that if I add a Robolectric Test Class to that package then when I execute `./gradlew test` all the functional test are ran along with the Robolectric/Unit Tests.

Is best practice to be using a different test package for my unit tests? And if that's the case then will I have to configure the Gradle `test` task to look at only the unit test package?

I should mention that I'm on Android Studio 1.0, Gradle 1.0, and Robolectric 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

`./gradle test` runs all the test in your project. You will likely have (at least) two modules in your project, lets call them `app` and `robolectric-tests`.

You can tell Gradle to run a task on a specific module by using `./gradlew :module:task`. So in your case, you could run `./gradlew :robolectric-tests:test` to run only your Robolectric tests.